# Creating a Wordpress app using Microsoft Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

I am trying to create a Wordpress app using the official WordPress resource from the market place.

I fill out all of my settings as usual, like the website name, resource group and also, the ClearDB database I made.

Everything shows up correctly. My website name is valid, the resource group is correct etc.

But when I hit create, My app name is labelled as "not available" for about 1 second. This then goes away and the "create" button greys out, and now says validating. When this is done, I am taken to a page with an icon of a cloud with a drop of rain. Chrome then prompts me that my unsaved changes will be discarded. I click cancel and it appears again in an instant. If I click 'okay', then everything is cleared, and I ha ve to enter it all over again, only for the whole problem to occur once again.

Please Help!!!!

Thanks, Sean.

Comment: try incognito mode, another browser, another pc

Comment: Tried that, It still doesn't work ):

Comment: well, I can assure you - Azure works. so the problem is on your side.